# Refresh Property when property change within other object

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, observable

Lets say I have the following classes (Model)

```
public class Employee : ObservableBase {
  private int _id;
  public int Id {
    get { return _id; }
    set { this.Update( x => x.Id, ( ) => _id = value, _id, value ); }
  }

  private string _name;
  public string Name {
    get { return _name; }
    set { this.Update( x => x.Name, ( ) => _name = value, _name, value ); }
  }

  private EmployeeStatus _level;
  public EmployeeStatus Level {
    get { return _level; }
    set { this.Update( x => x.Level, ( ) => _level = value, _level, value ); }
  }

  private RecordState _state;
  public RecordState State {
    get { return _state; }
    set { this.Update( x => x.State, ( ) => _state = value, _state, value ); }
  }

}

public class Enums {
  public enum EmployeeStatus {
    Junior = 1,
    Medior = 2,
    Senior = 3
  }

  public enum RecordState {
    Add = 1,
    Edit = 2,
    Delete = 3
  }
}
```

And I write a wrap a class around it to be able to expose extra properties (To determine visibility and disable/enable on my View on certain controls):

```
public class EmployeeCustom : ObservableBase {

  private Employee _employee;
  public Employee Employee {
    get { return _employee; }
    set { this.Update( x => x.Employee, ( ) => _employee = value, _employee, value ); }
  }

  public Visibility SeniorTestVisible {
    get { return Employee.Level == EmployeeStatus.Senior && Employee.State == RecordState.Add ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; }
  }


}
```

My **EmployeeCustom** class are used in my View as DataContext
How do I determine when my **State** or **Level** has changed, so that my SeniorTestVisible can "Refresh" if any of these properties change within the Employee object. Please note I am not allowed to make any changes to the Employee Class. Only in EmployeeCustom.

Comment: this sounds like your homework then?

Comment: Where is your `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation?

Comment: rather than reinventing the wheel, consider using mvvmlight and then look into the RaisePropertyChanged functionality. That way you can update an property and also force another property to be treated as updated at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I determine when my `State` or `Level` has changed, so that my `SeniorTestVisible` can "Refresh" if any of these properties change within the `Employee` object.

You hook up an event handler for the event that the `Employee` class (hopefully) raises whenever any of these properties are changed, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `SeniorTestVisible` property of the `EmployeeCustom` class whenever this happens, e.g.:

```
public class EmployeeCustom : ObservableBase
{
    private Employee _employee;
    public Employee Employee
    {
        get { return _employee; }
        set
        {
            if (_employee != null)
                _employee.PropertyChanged -= OnEmployeePropertyChanged;
            if(value != null)
                value..PropertyChanged += OnEmployeePropertyChanged;

            this.Update(x => x.Employee, () => _employee = value, _employee, value);
        }
    }

    public Visibility SeniorTestVisible
    {
        get { return Employee.Level == EmployeeStatus.Senior && Employee.State == RecordState.Add ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; }
    }

    public void OnEmployeePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == "Level" || e.PropertyName == "State")
        {
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SeniorTestVisible");
        }
    }
}
```

If the `Employee` class doesn't raise any event, you can't know.